# Comparação de inteiros em Java

Tags: java

```
Integer valor = 127;
Integer valor2 = 127;

System.out.printIn(valor == valor2);
```

> Output: true

```
Integer valor = 128;
Integer valor2 = 128;

System.out.printIn(valor == valor2);
```

> Output: false

Porque isso acontece?

Comment: Acredito que tenha a ver com algum autoboxing que essa classe realiza internamente. Posso chutar que, por ter 127, ela faz autoboxing para byte, o que justifica o resultado da primeira retornar true. Já na segunda, parece que não ocorre autoboxing nem pra int, e acaba por comparar objetos, o que justifica o resultado false, já que objetos não podem ser comparados corretamente com `==`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A classe Integer faz parte do pacote de classe *Wrapper* e não de tipo primitivo de dados, como o `int`. O que chamamos de *Wrapper* é uma classe que representa um tipo primitivo. Por exemplo o *Wrapper* de `int` é o `Integer`. Perceba que o *Wrapper* começa com letra maiúscula, ele segue a mesma nomenclatura que qualquer outra classe, pois ele também é uma.

Por tal motivo o operador `==` não é recomendado para comparar valores da classe `Integer`. Para isso usamos outro comparador, o `equals`.

**Exemplo 1:**

```
Integer valor = 127;
Integer valor2 = 127;

System.out.println(valor == valor2); // Saída: true
System.out.println(Objects.equals(valor, valor2)); // Saída: true
```

Perceba que nos dois casos retorna true.

Agora vejamos outro exemplo:

```
Integer valor3 = 128;
Integer valor4 = 128;

System.out.println(valor3 == valor4); // Saída: false
System.out.println(Objects.equals(valor3, valor4)); // Saída: true
```

Mas a pergunta é: por que o `==` funciona para o `Integer` 127 e não para o `Integer` 128?

A resposta é simples: A JVM está armazenando valores inteiros em cache. Portanto o `==` funciona apenas para números entre -128 e 127. Este cache é mencionado na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) do método `valueOf`, que, a primeira impressão é chamado internamente quando se faz [autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445024/does-autoboxing-call-valueof), um recurso que automaticamente converte tipos primitivos em seu *wrapper* equivalente.

**Observação:** Caso utilizasse o tipo primitivo de dados `int` uma simples comparação utilizando o comparador `==` funcionaria.

```
int valorTeste = 128;
int valorTeste2 = 128;

System.out.println(valorTeste == valorTeste2); // Saída: true
```

Comment: É interessante notar que este cache é mencionado [na documentação do método `valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), que [parece ser o método chamado internamente quando se faz autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31445024)

Comment: Exatamente @hkotsubo, bem lembrado.

Answer (score 15):

```
Integer valor = 127;
```

cria um Objeto da classe `Integer` que representa o respectivo inteiro, ao contrário de

```
int i = 127;
```

que *apenas* cria um primitivo.

O operador `==` serve apenas para testar se se trata da mesma instância, não compara o conteúdo das instâncias. Portanto normalmente irá retornar `false` para duas instâncias de `Integer` mesmo que representem o mesmo valor.

A classe `Integer` possui um mecanismo para armazenar uma certa quantidade de instâncias (cache) para evitar a criação de novas instâncias repetidas. Normalmente esse *cache* é especificado para armazenar os inteiros entre -128 e 127 ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))). O valor máximo pode ser alterado através da propriedade `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`. O mínimo é fixo em `-128`. O compilador usa esse método para a criação (ou conversão de `int`) do `Integer`.

Então se usar

```
Integer valor = 127;
```

O compilador está traduzindo isso para algo semelhante à

```
Integer valor = Integer.valueOf(127);
```

e acaba usando a instância armazenada no cache, também para

```
Integer valor2 = 127;
```

e o resultado de `valor == valor2` vai ser `true` pois se trata da mesma instância.

Se por exemplo fizer

```
Integer valor2 = new Integer(127);
```

estará criando uma nova instância e o resultado de `valor == valor2` vai ser `false`.

*Obs*: semelhante acontece na classe `String` onde os valores constantes são *internalizados*, ver método [intern()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()). Exemplo: `new String("abc") != "abc"`

Answer (score 9):

Primeiro é importante entender que `Integer` é uma classe em `java`, enquanto `int` é um tipo primitivo.

Desta forma, ao usar `Integer valor` está criando um objeto. Isso serve, por exemplo, para fazer operações que um tipo primitivo não pode fazer, como conter nulos ou servir de chave para um objeto `HashMap`, que requer um objeto como chave.

Assim, a sua comparação se fosse feita usando `int`, retornaria `true`:

```
int valor-18;
int valor2 = 128;
System.out.println(valor == valor2);
```

Por que a diferença com Integer, sendo que com 127 retornar true?

Lendo essa resposta do SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1700109/4730201
É a apresentada a documentação do java: [http://java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7), que cita, em tradução livre:

> Se o valor p sendo *boxed* for verdadeiro, falso, um byte, um
>   caractere no intervalo \ u0000 a \ u007f ou um int ou um número curto
>   entre -128 e 127, então faz r1 e r2 serem os resultados de quaisquer
>   duas conversões de *boxing*  p. É sempre o caso que r1 == r2

Lembrando que *boxing* é o processo de conversão de um tipo de valor (*value type*) para um objeto de um classe, ou para o tipo de interface de uma classe, por exemplo, converter um tipo primitivo *int* para uma classe *Integer*.

Em resumo, o problema da diferença nos valores 128, é que até 127, o java faz esse *boxing*, resultando em dois objetos iguais, e o valor 128 ou mais se comporta diferente, gerando dois objetos não necessariamente iguais.

Se o *boxing* não for automático, mesmo com o valor 127 resultará em objetos diferentes, teste assim:

```
Integer valor = new Integer(127);
Integer valor2 = new Integer(127);
```

Como `Integer` gera um objeto, se você fizer assim, retornará true:

```
Integer valor = new Integer(128);
Integer valor2 = valor;
```

Montei um fiddle com esses testes: [jdoodle.com/a/DAM](http://jdoodle.com/a/DAM)